How to read/import CUE files using Audio Tools Library (ATL)?
If I have understand correctly it is possible to handle CUE files (usually used with flac files) by Audio Tools Library (ATL). But I don't find any way to do this. So, is there really any way to read cue file and possible to export it after made some changes? Short example would be nice. Thanks!

What do you mean by CUE File, I Found on Wikipedia it's just saying that it's just a plain Text file ... if you understand the format of text and understand how to edit it with notepad for example then the edit from c# should be as easy as editing text files

Recommend you to read Cue sheet syntax to get familiar with the text syntax and format

Yes, I know CUE file is text file, but I mean that it is possible to read CUE file inside as playlist. (get play position, length etc. info)
